# Can get specify points' coordinate from output image using OpenCV remap?

Tags: python, opencv, remap

I used OpenCV remap function to unwarp an image and I want to crop some specifies field on unwarp image.
How can I convert exactly coordinate on origin image to unwarp image?

```
output = cv2.remap(img,xmap,ymap,cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Could you post source image and desired output?

Comment: I added example image in edit